# Spark Sql, unable to query multiple possible values in a array

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, document-database, bigdata

I have the data schema of LinkeIn account as shown below. I need to query the skills which is in the for of array, where array may contains either JAVA OR java OR Java or JAVA developer OR Java developer.

[image: Linkedin dataschema]

```
Dataset<Row> sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people"
            + " WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(skills,'Java') "
            + " OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(skills,'JAVA')"
            + " OR ARRAY_CONTAINS(skills,'Java developer') "
            + "AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(experience['description'],'Java developer')"  );
```

The above query is what i have tried and please suggest any better way.and also how to use case-insentive query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.printschema()

root
 |-- skills: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)


df.show()

+--------------------+
|              skills|
+--------------------+
|        [Java, java]|
|[Java Developer, ...|
|               [dev]|
+--------------------+
```

Now lets register it as a temp table:

```
>>> df.registerTempTable("t")
```

Now, we will explode the array, convert each element as lower case and query using LIKE operator:

```
>>> res = sqlContext.sql("select skills, lower(skill) as skill from (select skills, explode(skills) skill from t) a where lower(skill) like '%java%'")
>>> res.show()
+--------------------+--------------+
|              skills|         skill|
+--------------------+--------------+
|        [Java, java]|          java|
|        [Java, java]|          java|
|[Java Developer, ...|java developer|
|[Java Developer, ...|      java dev|
+--------------------+--------------+
```

Now, you can do a distinct on skills field.

Comment: can you help me more ?

Comment: please post your question, will help as far as I can :)

Comment: Ayan Guha . please have a look at this link . i wan unable to pos uqestion from this account so i have done it with another question .    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634284/how-to-convert-json-arraystring-to-csv-in-spark-sql

Comment: can you vote up my question @Ayan Gupta .. i am unable to post other questions due to 0 vote in my question