# How to convert json array<String> to csv in spark sql

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I have tried this query to get required experience from linkedin data.

[image: click here for my data]

```
 Dataset<Row> filteredData = spark
                    .sql("select full_name ,experience from (select *, explode(experience['title']) exp from tempTable )"
                            + "  a where lower(exp) like '%developer%'");
```

But I got this error:

[image: click here for error I got]

and finally I tried  but I got more rows with the same name .

```
Dataset<Row> filteredData = spark
                    .sql("select full_name ,explode(experience) from (select *, explode(experience['title']) exp from tempTable )"
                            + "  a where lower(exp) like '%developer%'");
```

Please give me hint, how to convert array of string to comma separated string in the same column.

Comment: can u share more information about the code and sample data

Comment: actually i am writing code in spark

Comment: thanks,but can u share ur sample code in json format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply UDF for making a comma separate string

Create UDF like this

```
def mkString(value: WrappedArray[String]): String = value.mkString(",")
```

Register UDF in sparkSQL context

```
sqlContext.udf.register("mkstring", mkString _)
```

Apply it on SparkSQL query

```
sqlContext.sql(select mkstring(columnName) from tableName)
```

it will return comma separate value of array

Comment: if the column has array of <String > use concat_ws(string delimiter, array<string>)    else  concat_ws(',',collect_set(cast(date as string)))

Comment: Thanks man you guided me . :) i did in a way how you suggest ..  :)

Comment: @AshisParajuli  if it is hlpful for u so plz accept the answer